# How do you break down the meaning of a person's name?

Tags: meaning, etymology, names

I have been trying to figure out what the name "Krew" means, and have had little luck with common "name-meaning" websites. **It got me curious about how to break the name down myself.**

Is there a standard process for determining the meaning of a name? Could it have to do with another language, or will the meaning vary from language to language?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because "names" don't necessarily (or even *usually*) mean anything at all. And even if they *do*, that's not really "use of English" as covered by ELU.

Comment: Krew means Crew: [part of] a group.  It came through Old French, from a Latin root meaning 'reinforcements [of troops]'.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Actually, isn't etymology on topic?

Comment: A name does not necessarily mean anything at all, and may simply have been chosen because of the way it sounds or is spelled, or what it vaguely evokes. Organization and product names are arbitrary, hence sites like [Novanym](https://novanym.com/), or the car naming industry, but it's also true of individuals. I had a co-worker whose parents named her *Tisa* because they liked the name *Lisa* with their surname, but wanted her name to be more unique— thereby condemning her to a life of explaining *spelled like 'Lisa' with a 'T'*, but indeed unique.

Comment: This type of question is probably a better fit for the Genealogy & Family History site, which has [answered name meaning questions in the past](https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1755). (However, I am not a member of that site, so you should ask on their meta if you have any questions.)

Comment: @Laurel, the English Language Learners subsite is the only possible migration location. Do you know how I can migrate to the genealogy site?

Comment: @KevBot You'd have to flag this post for moderator attention.

Comment: I've asked Genealogy SE mods if they will take the question.

Comment: Genealogy SE mods declined the question but there was a suggestion to try the names section of [Cyndi's List](https://cyndislist.com/names/).

Answer (score 1):

To discover the meaning of names, use standard scholarly research techniques and practices. In the case of an anthroponym ("a personal name", *OED*), historical research may be supplemented with language research; in the case of an English language anthroponym, depending on its antiquity, the assignment of a name has often followed specific historical paths.

For example, 'Krew', if it is an English surname of long standing, may have come from an early spelling variant of 'crow', the English intransitive verb meaning to "utter the loud cry of a cock", or sometimes (rarely) the cry of other birds (ravens). *OED* scholars found a variant of the verb with the spelling *krew* in documents from Middle English into the 1500s.

The somewhat cursory historical research I undertook suggests 'Krew' is not an English surname of long standing. It does not appear as an anthroponym in the popular newspapers available online at [The British Newspaper Archive](https://www.britishnewspaperarchive.co.uk/), and its only appearance therein as an early (1700s) place name (one common route for anthroponym assignment) is as the name of an inholding of private lands to let:

> To be let, from the 1st of May 1759, for any Term agreed on, by Silver Oliver, Esq., Part of his Estate in the County of Leitrim, the Farm and Lands of Mullenadarragh, Upper and Lower Aghavullen, Ag haran, Drombrenlish, **Krew**, ....
>
> *Pue's Occurrences* 21 October 1758

Further, 'Krew' does not appear in the [list of surnames at a genealogical site compilation of some records for County Leitrim](http://www.connorsgenealogy.net/Leitrim/surnames.htm).

The foregoing facts suggest that the name was adopted more recently, perhaps as a transliterated spelling of a name from another language than English, or from a monicker or nickname based on 'crew' (common definition) or 'krewe' (an "organization or association devoted to organizing and participating in parades and other events as part of a carnival", *OED*) in their more recent or modern senses.

Without more details about the name 'Krew', its history and especially its language of origin, it is impossible to tell whether your question is in scope on this site.